# Laravel not finding the App\Auth from model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and am reading up a bit on morphToMany relationships.

My naming for this model is a bit odd, but please bear with me.

I have a Drool model, and im building a getIsDrooledAttribute function.

The function which is returning errors is the following;

```
$drool = $this->drools()->whereUserId(Auth::id())->first();
return (!is_null($drool)) ? true : false;
```

and the error im getting is

```
Class 'App\Auth' not found
```

I am running the standard auth system created when running `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Auth` is a facade, so you need to add this to the top of the class to make it work:

```
use Auth;
```

Or use full namespace:

```
\Auth::id()
```

Or just use `auth()` global helper:

```
auth()->id()
```

Comment: Ah yes .. Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

`Auth` is a facade, so you need to add this code at the top of your class:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`